# jQuery load() doesn't get updated result from file (?!)

Tags: jquery, load

I've looked for answers first, but nothing got my head clear around this so here it is...

HTML file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="new-task">
    <input id="task-field" type="text" name="task">
    <button type="submit">change value</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#new-task").submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var inputValue = $("#task-field").val();


        $.ajax({

            url: "ajaxRequest.php",
            data: "task="+inputValue


        });

    });

    $("#output").load("ajaxRequest.php");

});
```

PHP file:

```
if(isset($_GET['task'])) echo $_GET['task'];
else echo "get not set";
```

So i just want to output the $_GET value from php in the "output" div each time something is written and submitted through the form. Instead it will output "get not set" the first time the page is loaded and stays like that even if i submit a value. The browser's network tab shows the requests are being sent and a 'task' get variable is created ( created a screenshot - https://gyazo.com/2c45024df4338b0481da4494ba89e49e ), still it is not outputted. What am i missing? I must have understood something wrong...

Comment: Could it be that you load ajaxRequest.php before you've even completed the ajax request?  Remember js isn't like C# or php...It doesn't sit there and wait for ajax responses.  You'll need to use a callback or a promise for this to work correctly.

Comment: Why would the php load before the request is completed if the load() is placed after the ajax request? What's inside document.ready() won't execute in order? And won't be re-executed if an action took place (like pressing submit)?

Comment: The load() function is an ajax request as well.  The $.ajax function is inside the submit logic, but the load() is outside the submit function block, so the load only happens once when the page loads.  All subsequent submits make ajax requests, but nothing is done with the response.  For another example, you could replace the logic in the submit with $("#output").load("ajaxRequest.php?task="+$("#task-field").val());  since the load handles the response.

Comment: I figured, in the end. :D When i read again your answer from below it rang a bell to me. That is what i was not getting clear. Now i do so thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like it's only loading once when the page is ready since it's outside the submit function.  The other ajax call hits submits, but it looks like the code never reloads the data again other than the initial page load time.

Try adding .done() callback to load the data like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajaxRequest.php",
    data: "task="+inputValue
}).done(function(returnData){
     $("#output").html(returnData);
});
```

Not tested, so you may  have to tweak.

Comment: i did use 'success: function()' instead though :D seems a little easier to understand for me at the moment. I only just began to understand how AJAX works.